# how to change a button text in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, button, jquery-mobile, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change text on button using jquery mobile.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249256/change-text-on-button-using-jquery-mobile)

I need to change a button text, I am using jQuery mobile.

Here is my html:

```
<fieldset>
    <div><button type="submit" id="login_var">Login</button></div>
    <div><button type="reset" >Reset</button></div>
</fieldset>
```

I have tried all of the examples on this page:
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009524/change-button-text-jquery-mobile) and nothing is working for me.

Please help

Comment: with what text to replace, on which event?

Comment: I want to replace `Login` text with whatever text..something like `OK` Just to see how does it works. Don't worry about the event it is not important right now. I just need to access that text in the button and change it

Comment: in my case it is working as I use to change my text in place of Login write OK...

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava any example? how did yu change it?

Comment: @denonth actually I use it many application so I copy from one application   <fieldset class="ui-grid-c">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="reset" data-theme="d" data-mini="true" class="edit">Edit</button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-mini="true">Check In</button></div>
     </fieldset>

Comment: @denonth-Have you clear all  history and cookie may be problem with that only?

Comment: I don't know if you understand me correctly. I need to change the text of the button dynamically in another words I need to access a button variable and change the text

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava what you have sent is a example of how to create a button

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava I need to access the variable from the javascript and change its value

Comment: i can solve you this but in jquery , let me know

Comment: yes in jQuery please. I am using jQuery mobile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had to do the same thing before, it's really not as obvious to do as it should be. Since jQM adds `span` tags inside your button, you need to change the value inside the span:

```
$("#login_var .ui-btn-text").text("NewText");
```

Similarly, if you wanted to change the icon, you could do:

```
$("#login_var .ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-arrow-l").addClass("ui-icon-arrow-r");
```

**Edit:**
Sorry I just noticed the link you posted in the question has the same solution, and you said that doesn't work for you. Maybe if you changed your buttons to

```
<a data-role="button"></a>
```

Instead of `<button></button>`?

Comment: this is actually working. Problem was in <button> tags, when I have put <a> everything is working

Answer (score 6):

Yeah you can use

```
$(function(){
  $('#login_var').text('Ok').button('refresh');
});
```

As per http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html, there are only three methods you can call on a button.

Comment: I just need to change the text and not to call the button. As I have a select menu and when you click on certain value I need to change the text of the button.

Comment: @denonth have a look I edit my changes and copy after </body>